# Can someone confirm this hadees?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I was listening to a lecture, scholar said in sahih al jami #59, prophet peace be upon him said he saw Allah in dreams. Just wanted to k ow if this hadees is actually there and is true or not?
I can not find sahih al jami online.

Comment: This is a very vague information about the hadith content. Further Sahih al-Jami' is also vague it could be a reference to several books like the Sahih's of the imam's al-Bukhari, Muslim and also to the boook of imam at-Tirmidhi , to name some. And furthermore the hadith numbers are a matter of edition so each printed version of an editor or publisher might be different then another. As none of the hadith scholars have added these numbers in the original book. As all hadith was transmitted orally before compiling it in a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you may mean one of those:
In Jami' at-Tirmidhi:

- On the authority of [Mu'ad ibn Jabal](https://sunnah.com/urn/742690) which was also compiled by imam Ahmad in his al-Musnad via ibn 'Abbas and a-Darami via 'Abdurrahman ibn 'Aaish (this narration is doubtful) etc.:

> "One morning, the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) was prevented from coming to us for Salat As-Subh, until we were just about to look for the eye of the sun (meaning sunrise). Then he came out quickly, had the Salat prepared for. The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) performed the Salat, and he performed his Salat in a relatively quick manner. When he said the Salam, he called aloud with his voice saying to us: 'Stay in your rows as you are.' Then he turned coming near to us, then he said: 'I am going to narrate to you what kept me from you this morning: I got up during the night, I performed Wudu and prayed as much as I was able to, and I dozed off during my Salat, and fell deep asleep. Then I saw my Lord, Blessed and Most High, in the best of appearances. He said: 'O Muhammad!' I said: 'My Lord here I am my Lord!' He said: 'What is it that the most exalted group busy themselves with?' I said: 'I do not know Lord.' And He said it three times." He said: "So I saw Him place His Palm between my shoulders, and I sensed the coolness of His Fingertips between my breast. Then everything was disclosed for me, and I became aware. So He said: 'O Muhammad!' I said: 'Here I am my Lord!' He said: 'What is it that the most exalted group busy themselves with?' I said: 'In the acts that atone.' He said: 'And what are they?' I said: 'The footsteps to the congregation, the gatherings in the Masajid after the Salat, Isbagh Al-Wudu during difficulties.' He said: 'Then what else?' I said: 'Feeding others, being lenient in speech, and Salat during the night while the people are sleeping.' He said: 'Ask.' I said: 'O Allah! I ask of you the doing of the good deeds, avoiding the evil deeds, loving the poor, and that You forgive me, and have mercy upon me. And when You have willed Fitnah in the people, then take me without the Fitnah. And I ask You for Your love, the love of whomever You love, and the love of the deeds that bring one nearer to Your love.'" The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "Indeed it is true, so study it and learn it."

Note that the best support for at least a qualification as "hassan" for this hadith is the amount of his paths. But on the whole none of them is free of doubts.
Imam at-Tirmidhi himself added a statement about the authenticity of this version saying:
 <sup>In the following I will translate from Arabic language, as these translations are of my own take them carefully!.

Note that I've added some inline comments in the translation between brackets</sup>

> قَالَ أَبُو عِيسَى هَذَا حَدِيثٌ حَسَنٌ صَحِيحٌ ‏.‏ سَأَلْتُ مُحَمَّدَ بْنَ إِسْمَاعِيلَ عَنْ هَذَا الْحَدِيثِ فَقَالَ هَذَا حَدِيثٌ حَسَنٌ صَحِيحٌ ‏.‏
> Abu 'Isa (imam at-Tirmidhi) said: This is a hadith which is hassan (good), sahih (sane). I've asked about it Muhammad ibn 'Isma'il (imam al-Bukhari) and he said it is hassan, sahih.
>
> وَقَالَ هَذَا أَصَحُّ مِنْ حَدِيثِ الْوَلِيدِ بْنِ مُسْلِمٍ عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ يَزِيدَ بْنِ جَابِرٍ ‏.‏ قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا خَالِدُ بْنُ اللَّجْلاَجِ حَدَّثَنِي عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ عَائِشٍ الْحَضْرَمِيُّ قَالَ سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَذَكَرَ الْحَدِيثَ وَهَذَا غَيْرُ مَحْفُوظٍ ‏.‏ هَكَذَا ذَكَرَ الْوَلِيدُ فِي حَدِيثِهِ عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ عَائِشٍ قَالَ سَمِعْتُ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏.‏ ‏.
> He further said: this is more sahih than the hadith of al-Walid ibn Muslim from 'Abdurrahman ibn Yazeed ibn Jabir who said we were infromed by Khalid ibn al-Lajlaaj who said I was informed by 'Abdurrahman ibn 'Aaish al-Hadramy who said he heard the Messenger of Allah, Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him and mentioned the hadith and this is not memorized. This way al-Walid has mentioned in his (version of the) hadith from 'Abdurrahman ibn 'Aaish said: "I heard the Messenger of Allah, Allah's prayers and blessing be upon him."
>
> وَرَوَى بِشْرُ بْنُ بَكْرٍ عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ يَزِيدَ بْنِ جَابِرٍ هَذَا الْحَدِيثَ بِهَذَا الإِسْنَادِ عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ عَائِشٍ عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏.‏ وَهَذَا أَصَحُّ ‏.‏ وَعَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ عَائِشٍ لَمْ يَسْمَعْ مِنَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم
> And Bishr ibn Bakr narrated this hadith from Aburrahman ibn Yazeed ibn Jabir via the same isnaad (path or narrator chain) frp, 'Abdurrhamn ibn 'Aish from the Messenger of Allah, Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him. While this is more sahih (correct). (As) 'Abdurrahman ibn 'Aaish didn't hear from the prophet, Allah's prayers and blessings be upon him.

This statement must be understood in the context of the terminology of earlier scholars, it only says that this narrator chain is more trustworthy than the other.
On the whole none of the narrator chains is without any doubt perfectly trustworthy. Some scholars have considered some of the chains as more reliable than others, but most of the chains and versions of the hadith have been declared as da'if (weak). This hadith is present with many variations in the "'Ilal علل" (Issues) books of scholars of hadith.

- On the authorithy of [ibn 'Abbas](https://sunnah.com/urn/742670):

> from Ibn 'Abbas that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: "During the night, my Lord, Blessed is He, and Most High, came to me in the best of appearances." He (one of the narrators) said - I think he said it was during a dream - "So he said: 'O Muhammad! Do you know in what the most exalted group busy themselves with?'" He said: "I said: 'No.'" He said: "So He placed His Hand between my shoulders, until I sensed its coolness between my breast." - or he said: "on my throat, so I knew what was in the heavens, and what was in the earth. He said: 'O Muhammad! Do you know in what the most exalted group busy themselves with?' I said: 'Yes, in the acts that atone: and the acts that atone are; lingering in the Masjid after the Salat, walking on the feet to the congregation, Isbagh Al-Wudu, in difficulty, and whoever does that, he lives in goodness and dies upon goodness, and his wrongs shall be like that of the day his mother bore him.' He said: 'O Muhammad! When you have performed Salat then say: 'O Allah! Indeed I ask of You, the doing of good deeds, avoiding the evil deeds, and loving the poor. And when you have willed Fitnah for your slave, then take me to You, without making me suffer from Fitnah.'" He [the Prophet (ﷺ)] said: "And the acts that raise ranks are spreading the Salam, feeding others, and Salat during the night, while the people are sleeping."

See also -in Arabic- fatwa on islamqa #[273377](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/273377/%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%AD-%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%8A%D8%AB-%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%89-%D9%81%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%85%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B6).